# Multiselect values not getting saved in hook_settings()?

Tags: forms, hooks

This is the code I have implemented in my module which is working fine!

```
/*
 * This is a helper()
 */
function MYMODULE_feeds($page_id = '') { 
  foreach($pagefeed['data'] as $feedval) {  
    $post_type[] = $feedval['type'];  
    if ($feedval['type'] == 'photo') {
      if(array_key_exists('message',$feedval)) {
          $messageFeed[] =  $feedval['message'];
          if ($timeshow == 1) {
            $created_statmp = $feedval['created_time'];
          }
          $i++;
      }
      if($i == variable_get('no_feeds')) {
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  $post_type_unique = array_unique($post_type);
  $post_type_unique_serial = array_values($post_type_unique);
  variable_set('post_type_unique_serial', $post_type_unique_serial);
  return theme('MYMODULE_feed_theme', array('pagefeeds' => $messageFeed, 'time_stamp' => $created_statmp));
}
```

After that I have done this in my module's `admin.inc` file

```
/*
 * Implements hook_settings()
 */
function MYMODULE_settings($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['MYMODULE']['post_type'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => 'Select your post type(s) to show',
    '#default_value' => variable_get('post_type_unique_serial'),
    '#options' => variable_get('post_type_unique_serial'),
    '#multiple' => TRUE,
  );
  return system_settings_form($form);
}
```

Problem is that, I'm getting the values there, but when I'm saving that every field is saving the updated values, expect this field.

I'm not getting where I've made the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a very similar issue some while ago, here is the solution which should work for you:

```
/*
 * Implements hook_settings()
 */
function MYMODULE_settings($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['MYMODULE']['post_type'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => 'Select your post type(s) to show',
    '#default_value' => variable_get('post_type', 0), // Here instead of 'post_type_unique_serial', you should use 'post_type'
    '#options' => variable_get('post_type_unique_serial'),
    '#multiple' => TRUE,
  );
  return system_settings_form($form);
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

1) If `variable_get('post_type_unique_serial')` returns an array to populate the options, then it can not also be used for setting the default value, as this should be a single key within the array.

2) Generally it is good practice to use the same name for the variable as the form element if it is being used to set the default value eg `$form['MYMODULE']['post_type']` and `'#default_value' => variable_get('post_type'),`

Comment: Thanks for your reply but what if I want save the multiple value for the select list, how should I pass the multiple keys for the same!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it in wrong way. Check my comment in front of `#default_value` and `#options`.

```
/*
 * Implements hook_settings()
 */
function MYMODULE_settings($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['MYMODULE']['post_type'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => 'Select your post type(s) to show',
    '#default_value' => variable_get('post_type', array()), // Selected value will saved as a variable with same name as field's name
    '#options' => $option_array, // Here paas the options list which should be same as default value
    '#multiple' => TRUE,
  );
  return system_settings_form($form);
}
```